# ArcGIS - How to move a graphic or symbol on the map

Tags: graphics, symbols, arcgis

I'm trying to create an overlay in ArcGIS that has moving graphics/symbols which are updated by coordinates received from roving devices. I'm able to display a simple symbol initially but cannot get it to move on the map. My test code is

```
            GraphicsOverlay machineOverlay = new GraphicsOverlay();
            MainMapView.GraphicsOverlays.Add(machineOverlay);
            MapPointBuilder rdLocation = new MapPointBuilder(150.864119200149, -32.3478640837185, SpatialReferences.Wgs84); 


            SimpleMarkerSymbol sRD1234 = new SimpleMarkerSymbol()
            {
                Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red,
                Size = 10,
                Style = SimpleMarkerSymbolStyle.Circle
            };

            Graphic graphicWithSymbol = new Graphic(rdLocation.ToGeometry(), sRD1234);
            machineOverlay.Graphics.Add(graphicWithSymbol);

            // here the red circle is displayed correctly on the map

            rdLocation.SetXY(150.887115, -32.357600); 
            rdLocation.ReplaceGeometry(rdLocation.ToGeometry());

            // here I expect the red circle to move but it doesn't
```

Do I need to trigger an event to "re-render" or refresh the overlay, or what do I need to do to get the graphic to move on my map?

There was a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72219182/can-graphics-overlay-be-used-to-constantly-update-location-marker-in-arcgis) and the answer was "just update the geometry" which is what I'm attempting to do, but with no success.

If there is an entirely different or better approach to moving markers on a map please suggest, I'm just getting started in the ArcGIS runtime.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching I replaced one line of code and its now working

```
//rdLocation.ReplaceGeometry(rdLocation.ToGeometry());
graphicWithSymbol.Geometry = rdLocation.ToGeometry();
```

It seems I misunderstood the function of `ReplaceGeometry()`. Any clarification on this would be helpful.